# How to get from sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document to table record in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

For example, if I query like so

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(DB_ID, TABLE_ID)
```

I can get both keywords and document_id's.  I want to go from document_id to the record involved.  There has to be some view that correlates the document_id to my primary key?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer at [Get Started With Full-Text Search](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269(v=sql.100).aspx):

> Note: **When your full-text key is an integer type (which is our recommendation), document_id maps directly to this value in the base table**. However, **if the full-text key is a non-integer type, document_id will not represent the full-text key in the base table. To identify the row in the base table returned by this dynamic management view (DMV), you must join it with the results returned by sys.sp_fulltext_keymappings**. You must store this stored procedure output in a temporary table before you can join the document_id column with the DocId column returned by the stored procedure. For more information on this stored procedure, see the "sys.sp_fulltext_keymappings" topic in SQL Server Books Online.